# SQL - Find & Replace Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to find data in a specific table then replace data in a specific column.  For example, in the Customer table, need to find everything associated with "1200" in the PO column, then once those records are located  replace data in the date column.  Right now, the incorrect date is showing against PO 1200.

Currently:

```
PO   1200
Date 12/15/14
```

Needs to be

```
PO   1200
Date 1/15/15
```

I currently already have other data with the 12/15/14 date so I can't just do a simple find 12/15/14 and replace with 1/15/15 because it will change other records that I must not change.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE is used to update, LIKE can be used to find those "1200" values. Good luck!

Comment: I would be easier to help you if you provide schema and sample data.

Comment: Can you find the data you need with a select statement? That would be the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    date = newDate
WHERE  PO = 1200
```

Another example with other options:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    columnName = GETDATE() --or something to get the date you want
WHERE  otherColumnName = someValue
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd assume it's because the structure isn't known.  There is no indication of a `PO` field.

Comment: I see - thank you all for adding some context.  I did see in the original question this line:  "associated with "1200" in the PO column" - which is why I used the name...  Doesn't really matter but thought I should explain.

Comment: @macoms01: Your answer is fine, all because OP didn't formatted the question which I have done now